# How to remove this two-piece door hinge?

Tags: doors, hinges

Trying to remove a door at my apartment, and it has a door hinge that looks like this

[image: hinge picture #1]

and here's an image of another one
[image: hinge picture #2]

They are both painted over quite a bit, so it's difficult to see how I'm supposed to attack it. Anyone familiar with these and how I should try to remove them?

Comment: Have you tried lifting up with the door open?

Comment: I tried this at first, but perhaps because of the paint and the old age, it wasn't budging. I then put a hammer underneath the door, and sort of used it to pull up harder, and it then started budging. It's now off! Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was difficult to pull up by hand, because of the paint and because it's been there for awhile. But I just used a lot of force at the bottom of the door (using a hammer handle to help me pry up) and I was able to start moving it and then got it off.

Comment: Give it a touch of grease or oil before re-assembling.